# Efficient T-SQL for adding missing dates with previous value

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table that shows inventory changes for items, like so

```
Item_ID | Date_ID   | Change | Inventory
 521    | 5/1/2010  | 56     | 56
 634    | 5/2/2010  | -12    | 42
 521    | 5/12/2010 | 3      | 59
```

I have a LU_Date table, and an LU_Item table with all items (that may or may not be present in the Inventory table.)

I need output that shows all dates for all items, with Inventory on that day, for example:

```
Item_ID | Date_ID   | Change | Inventory
521     | 4/30/2010 | 0      | 0
521     | 5/1/2010  | 56     | 56
521     | 5/2/2010  | 0      | 56
521     | 5/3/2010  | 0      | 56
521     | 5/4/2010  | 3      | 59
634     | 4/30/2010 | 0      | 54
634     | 5/1/2010  | 0      | 54
634     | 5/2/2010  | -12    | 42
632     | 4/30/2010 | 0      | 0
```

I've attempted solutions, but cannot seem to find an efficient query.  When using a solution such as this:

```
SELECT d.Date_ID,
ISNULL(r.Change,0) AS mnmt,
COALESCE(r.Inventory, S.Inventory) AS quantity
FROM dbo.LU_Date d 
CROSS JOIN LU_Item i
LEFT JOIN Fact_Inventory_ByDay r ON d.Date_ID=r.Date_ID AND r.Item_ID=i.Item_ID
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) Inventory
           FROM Fact_Inventory_ByDay b2 
           WHERE b2.Item_ID=i.Item_ID AND b2.Date_ID < d.Date_ID 
           ORDER BY b2.Date_ID DESC, b2.Item_ID DESC) AS S
    WHERE i.item_ID=@Item
```

I get unacceptable wait times (46 seconds for a single item, for example).
Does anyone have an elegant solution for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest optimization I can think of is to move the fetching of missing inventory rows into a second query that only runs for needed rows.

Give this a shot (This is freehand, so will probably be filled with bugs)

I assume the primary key on Fact_Inventory_ByDay is Inventory_ByDay_ID, also wasnt sure if there could be multiple inventory changes on the same day, so accounted for it.

```
SELECT
    D.Date_ID,
    I.Item_ID,
    COALESCE(SUM(FI.Change),0) AS Change,
    MAX(FI.Inventory_ByDay_ID) as MaxID,
INTO #TempRows
FROM
    dbo.LU_Date D
    JOIN LU_Item I
      ON I.Item_ID = @ItemID
    LEFT JOIN Fact_Inventory_ByDay FI
      ON FI.Date_ID = D.Date_ID AND FI.Item_ID = I.Item_ID
GROUP BY
    D.Date_ID,
    I.Item_ID


UPDATE
    #TempRows T
SET
    T.MaxID = ( SELECT TOP 1 FI.Inventory_ByDay_ID 
                FROM Fact_Inventory_ByDay FI
                WHERE FI.Date_ID < T.Date_ID
                AND FI.Item_ID = T.Item_ID
                ORDER BY FI.Date_ID DESC )
WHERE
    T.MaxID is NULL


SELECT
    T.Date_ID,
    T.Item_ID,
    T.Change,
    FI.Inventory
FROM 
    #TempRows
    JOIN Fact_Inventory_ByDay FI
      ON FI.Inventory_ByDay_ID = T.Inventory_ByDay_ID
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the cross join of LU_Date and LU_Item yields about 71 million rows, so storing that in a temp table isn't efficient.  Any other ideas?  And the inventory changes have already been aggregated by day, so there is only one row for a given day/item in Fact_Inventory_ByDay.

Comment: OK, didnt expect that many rows. If you need the info from all rows in the cross join then you have no option but to wait. I cant imagine you need all 71 million rows as output, if you dont, filter the query early so it doesnt bother loading them in the first place (hence joining on the @itemid). Other options are limiting the date range. The temp table shouldnt cause much overhead as it only selects the data you need to output anyway, and should save about 30 million subqueries from the initial query.

Comment: I am creating a view with this query, the expectation is it will be filtered on some criteria from the BI tool, but I have to provide an interface to all rows.

Comment: From my experience this would be typically done as an overnight batch job into another table, then the BI tool would access only the proccessed version of the table. You will not find a solution to this problem with an efficient query